# How to set a minimum size for a Window in wxRuby

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, wxruby

I'm doing a simple GUI using wxRuby. I have just only read the tutorials and FAQ on the official site of the gem, but there are just a few examples.

I want to know if there's a way (i'm sure there is a way but i don't know how to implement it) to set a minimum size of the windows...

For example, i want to set the minimum size of the windows to prevent the user from reducing the window to the level that the buttons and items aren't visible...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Wx::Sizer.set_min_size()](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/doc/sizer.html#Sizer_setminsize). As this is an abstract class, you need to use one of the sizers inheriting from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! set_min_size works on the app... it works on my frame object... i will check now on sizers...

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/doc/window.html

and this:

http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/doc/sizer.html